# Docker mounting remote volume with sshfs

Tags: docker, sshfs

I know that this question has been done on the web, but I am not able to find a suitable solution for me.

I have one server (VM1) with `sshfs` installed that should provide remote file system storage. I have another server (VM2) where containers are run, I would like that these containers use volumes hosted in VM1.

I followed this official docker [guide](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#use-a-volume-driver)
So in VM1 I ran:

```
docker plugin install vieux/sshfs DEBUG=1 sshkey.source=/home/debian/.ssh/
```

In VM 2 I ran:

```
docker volume create --name remotevolume -d vieux/sshfs -o sshcmd=debian@vm1:/home/debian/sshfs300 -o IdentityFile=/home/csicari/data/Mega/lavoro/keys/vm-csicari.key -o -o allow_other  -o nonempty
```

This is the inspect output:

```
[
  {
   "CreatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
   "Driver": "vieux/sshfs:latest",
   "Labels": {},
   "Mountpoint": "/mnt/volumes/895d7f7679f69131500c786d7fe5fdc1",
   "Name": "remotevolume",
   "Options": {
             "IdentityFile": "/home/csicari/data/Mega/lavoro/keys/vm-csicari.key",
             "sshcmd": "debian@vm1:/home/debian/sshfs300"
  },
  "Scope": "local"
  }
]
```

In VM1 I ran also:

```
docker run -it -v remotevolume:/home -d ubuntu
```

But I got this error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: VolumeDriver.Mount: sshfs command execute failed: exit status 1 (read: Connection reset by peer
). See 'docker run --help'.
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is a long back asked question maybe it will help other newbies. The remote VM `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file content check the property `PasswordAuthentication yes` 
If it is 'yes' we can use with password passing parameter. otherwise, change it to 'no' and restart the ssh or sshd service.

```
service ssh restart
service ssh status
```

And also PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration, so check that as well.

If it is AWS instance reset the password using the command `passwd` ubuntu # Here ubuntu is the default user in ec2 ubuntu instance